# JWT authentication without database access

Tags: java, spring, jwt, microservices

I am new to JWT. I create my own microservice and want to introduce JWT authentication. I have one website that issues a token and in the other I want to check the correctness of this token. I want to do this without connecting the second site to db. This approach seems to me appropriate and best for user data.

I have following payload of token:

```
{
  "sub": "Marek",
  "auth": [
    {
      "authority": "ROLE_USER"
    }
  ],
  "iat": 1574091010,
  "exp": 1574091210
}
```

Its my code:

WebSecurityConfig

```
@Autowired
    private JwtTockenCreator jwtTockenCreator;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf().disable();
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/user/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/user/addUser").permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();
        http.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/login");
        http.apply(new JWTConfigurer(jwtTockenCreator));

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
```

JwtTokenFilter

```
public class JwtTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private JwtTockenCreator jwtTockenCreator;

    public JwtTokenFilter(JwtTockenCreator jwtTockenCreator) {
        this.jwtTockenCreator = jwtTockenCreator;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse,
            FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String token = jwtTockenCreator.resolveToken(httpServletRequest);
        try {
            if (token != null && jwtTockenCreator.validateToken(token)) {
                Authentication auth = jwtTockenCreator.getAuthentication(token);
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
            }
        } catch (CustomException ex) {
            // this is very important, since it guarantees the user is not authenticated at
            // all
            SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
            httpServletResponse.sendError(ex.getHttpStatus().value(), ex.getMessage());
            return;
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
    }
}
```

JwtTockenCreator

```
public class JwtTockenCreator {

    @Value("${security.secretKey}")
    private  String secretKey;

     @PostConstruct
      protected void init() {
        secretKey = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(secretKey.getBytes());
      }
    public Authentication getAuthentication(String token) {

          Claims claims = Jwts.parser()
                    .setSigningKey(secretKey)
                    .parseClaimsJws(token)
                    .getBody();

          Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = Arrays.asList(claims.get(secretKey).toString().split(",")).stream()
                  .map(authority -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(authority)).collect(Collectors.toList());

          User principal = new User(claims.getSubject(), "", authorities);
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken( principal,"",authorities);
    }

    public String getUsernameFromToken(String token) {
        return Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(secretKey).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody().getSubject();
    }

    public String resolveToken(HttpServletRequest req) {
        String bearerToken = req.getHeader("Authorization");
        if (bearerToken != null && bearerToken.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            return bearerToken.substring(7);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public boolean validateToken(String token) {
        try {
            Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(secretKey).parseClaimsJws(token);
            return true;
        } catch (JwtException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
            throw new CustomException("Expired or invalid JWT token", HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
}
```

JWTConfigurer

```
public class JWTConfigurer extends SecurityConfigurerAdapter<DefaultSecurityFilterChain, HttpSecurity> {

    private JwtTockenCreator jwtTockenCreator;

    public JWTConfigurer(JwtTockenCreator jwtTockenCreator) {
    this.jwtTockenCreator = jwtTockenCreator;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      JwtTokenFilter customFilter = new JwtTokenFilter(jwtTockenCreator);
      http.addFilterBefore(customFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

UserController

```
@CrossOrigin
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Value("${hostname}")
    public String hostname;

    @Value("${user.port}")
    public String userPort;

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<String> login(@RequestBody User user) {
        String urlUser = hostname + userPort + "/user/login";
        String token = restTemplate.postForObject(urlUser, user, String.class);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(token);
    }

    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER')")
    @PostMapping("/addUser")
    public ResponseEntity<String> registerAction(@RequestBody User user) {
        String urlUser = hostname + userPort + "/user/addUser";
        String token = restTemplate.postForObject(urlUser, user, String.class);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(token);
    }

}
```

In Eclipse doesn't give any errors. That's why I don't know what I'm doing wrong

when I want to call / user / addUser and add a new user nothing happens. In the User service I call, I have a function responsible for adding users and it works correctly when I refer to it directly. And if I want to do it through my Rest Api it doesn't work anymore. And it is my problem that I do not know what can happen because I have no mistake. I remind you that I am still learning and I am asking for understanding

Comment: How can we help? You just say there are no errors, but don't tell what' not working. What's the problem?

Comment: when I want to call / user / addUser and add a new user nothing happens. In the User service I call, I have a function responsible for adding users and it works correctly when I refer to it directly. And if I want to do it through my Rest Api it doesn't work anymore. And it is my problem that I do not know what can happen because I have no mistake. I remind you that I am still learning and I am asking for understanding

Comment: First of all you should put spring security traces to debug level and see what is exactly the error or what is happening. Anyway I think there is one thing that is not totally correct. Here:
claims.get(secretKey).toString().split(",") you are trying to get the claim with the value of secretKey as name, so unless the value of secretKey is "auth" you won't get the authorities.